# how to include npm module in ionic1 using angualar js

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I am using ionic 1 with angular js but not able to use any npm module because it says "Error: Cannot find module 'bip39'"

Comment: can you put code. how you are including?

Comment: I installed bip32 (npm module) and use it in the service:
const bip32=require('bip32');
but i was getting errors

Comment: Can you give me an example how to use any npm module in ionic1 using angularjs

Comment: You need to give reference in index.html or try bower similar to npm but for plain javascript

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
<script src="node_modules/lib/bip38.js"></script>
```

Now not needed require("bip32"). You can use directly method and property.